# how to get value fields json like this mysql query

Tags: mysql, json

I have a table like this, i want to get value in fields type json(array), can it? the result attrs->>'$.target' == 1000 !

```
    id  | name  | attrs                       |
    1   | me    | {"target":["1000", "2000"]} |
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set path with array index for `JSON_EXTRACT` method:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(attrs, "$.target[0]") as test FROM tableName
where JSON_EXTRACT(attrs, "$.target[0]")  = '1000'
```

or more flexible solution:

```
SELECT  * FROM tableName
where JSON_EXTRACT(attrs, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(attrs,'all','1000')))  = '1000'
```